# Is it possible in an angular web app to run slightly different code on mobile using capacitor?

Tags: angular, admob, adsense, capacitor

I would like to add google ads to my app, but you need to use admob for web and adsense for mobile. First I wanted to use angular native, but I couldn't get it running and I found capacitor, but I don't quite understand their doc about Environment Specific Configurations. Any advice how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getPlatform()`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/web#getplatform) or [`isNativePlatform()`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/web#isnativeplatform) to check the environment:

```
if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
  // Native app running on Android or iOS
}
```